# Sumar elementos de una matriz de PHP

Tags: php

Tengo e la siguiente matriz, almacenada en un índice de la variable de sesión (`$_SESSION['carrito']`):

```
vardump($_SESSION['carito']);

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [evento] => 689382
            [cuota] => 2.10
            [equipoL] => Deportes Copiapo
            [equipoV] => Union San Felipe
            [tipo] => Match Winner
            [apostadoA] => local
            [total] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [evento] => 690693
            [cuota] => 1.50
            [equipoL] => Nautico Recife
            [equipoV] => Brasil DE Pelotas
            [tipo] => Match Winner
            [apostadoA] => local
            [total] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [evento] => 690695
            [cuota] => 3.00
            [equipoL] => CSA
            [equipoV] => Vasco DA Gama
            [tipo] => Match Winner
            [apostadoA] => empate
            [total] => 500
        )

);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es sumar todos los elementos `total` de la matriz completa.

He intentado recorriendo e la matriz, pero no encuentro la función o la forma de sumar esos campos específicos de cada elemento de la matriz.

Comment: In ciclo foreach te serviría

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He encontrado una solución muy práctica en el documentación oficial de PHP, utilizando 2 funciones de matrices.

La primera función que utilicé se llama [`array_column()`](https://php.net/es/array_column) que permite seleccionar en una variable todos datos de la matriz de una columna específica de la siguiente manera:

```
$totales = array_column($_SESSION['carito'], 'total');
```

De esta manera tenemos en la variable `$totales` una nueva matriz solo con los totales de cada elemento de la matriz `$_SESSION['carrito']`.

Lo único que debo hacer ahora es sumar esos elementos de la nueva matriz `$totales`. Para eso utilizamos otra función llamada [`array_sum()`](https://php.net/array_sum) de esta manera:

```
$grantotal = array_sum($totales);
```

Ahora la variable `$grantotal` tenemos la sumatoria de todos los elementos `total` que contiene mi matriz `$_SESSION['carito']`.

Comment: esta me parece una opción muy simplificada, excelente!

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! esa era la idea!

Comment: Te llevas mi +1, pero recuerda marcar tu respuesta como respuesta correcta para dar por cerrada esta pregunta.

Comment: Te sugiero que, además, eches un vistazo a [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/es/array_reduce) para cuando requieras hacer un cálculo previo con cada elemento (por ejemplo, aplicar un descuento o calcular el IVA aplicable a cada uno). Podrás hacer ese tratamiento previo y la suma en una única instrucción.

Answer (score 4):

Podrías probar adaptando la siguiente solución a tu código:

```
$suma = 0;
foreach ($arr_name as $item) {
    $suma += $item['total'];
}
```

Lo que haría el anterior código, es recorrer los arrays e ir sumando los items 'total', a la vez que lo almacena en la variable con el nombre "suma". En principio es una solución sencilla, pero funcional que ejemplifica lo que puedes hacer para aplicar a tu código.

Comment: Amigo excelente aporte muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para contestarme yo he llegado tambien a una solución que quiero publicar para que tengan tambien una alternativa, pero tu respuesta 100 de 100

Answer (score 2):

Traté de hacer el array lo más simple posible para que entiendas que solo debes leer lo que necesitas.

Lo importante es recorrer el array, y obtener los valores uno a uno para usarlos como quieras, en este caso, hacer la suma.

```
<?php

//Ejemplo de array
$carrito = [
    array(
        "total" => 100,
        "nombre" => "nombre"
    ),
    array(
        "total" => 200,
        "nombre" => "nombre"
    ),
    array(
        "total" => 300,
        "nombre" => "nombre"
    ),
    array(
        "total" => 400,
        "nombre" => "nombre"
    ),
    array(
        "total" => 500,
        "nombre" => "nombre"
    )
];

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($carrito);
echo "</pre>";

//Obtención de sumas
$suma = 0;
foreach ($carrito as $c) {
    echo $c["total"] . "</br>"; //Mostramos la variable a usar
    $suma += $c["total"]; //Usamos la variable total
}
echo "</br>";
//Mostrar el total
echo "El total seria: " . $suma;
```

Comment: excelente aporte mi amigo, te agradezco de antemano por tomarte un tiempo para responderme yo he llegado a otra solución utilizando array_column(); y array_sum(); que quiero publicar para que tengan varias alternativas quienes puedan leer este post, pero tu respuesta excelente, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Publicala como tu propia respuesta ;) es más que aceptado !

Comment: Recuerda que `echo` es una construcción del lenguaje que tiene un número indeterminado de parámetros. Por lo tanto, no necesitas concatenar cadenas antes de pasarlas como parámetro a `echo`,  puedes usar cada cadena como un parámetro diferente `echo "El total seria: ", $suma;`. Con este método evitas una operación de concatenación de cadenas de caracteres que no es necesario realizar.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la respuesta has propuesto basada en [`array_column()`](https://php.net/es/array_column) y [`array_sum()`](https://php.net/es/array_sum) es correcta y funciona perfectamente en pequeñas cantidades de datos, no escala correctamente en uso de memoria al aumentar el número de elementos de la matriz.

Esto es debido a que necesitas crear una matriz auxiliar que contiene todos los datos que posteriormente pasarás a `array_sum()`, consumiendo una cantidad de memoria que podría evitarse.

Para evitar esa matriz intermedia (y el uso de memoria relacionado) puedes usar la función [`array_reduce()`](https://php.net/es/array_reduce) de la siguiente manera:

```
$grantotal = array_reduce(
    $_SESSION['carrito'],
    function ($acumulador, $elemento) {
        return $acumulador + $elemento['total'];
    }
);
```

Si estás usando PHP 7.4 o superior entonces puedes usar las [funciones flecha](https://www.php.net/es/arrow) para quedarse como:

```
$grantotal = array_reduce(
    $_SESSION['carrito'],
    fn($acumulador, $elemento) => $acumulador+ $elemento['total']
);
```

Básicamente funciona como una versión alternativa de:

```
$acumulador = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['carrito'] as $elemento) {
    $acumulador += $elemento['total'];
}
```

La ventaja de usar estos dos métodos es que escalan correctamente en uso de memoria gracias a no tener que crear la matriz intermedia donde almacenar los valores extraídos para ser sumados posteriormente.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de hacer este tipo de cálculos con elementos de matrices sería con una reducción:

```
$total = array_reduce($_SESSION['carito'], function($sum, $item) {
  return $sum + $item['total'];
});
```

De esta forma iteras la matriz y vuelcas el cálculo directamente sobre una variable.

Te recomiendo echar un ojo a la documentación
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: Gracias por implementar en una respuesta la sugerencia que hice hace una media hora en los comentarios. Por desgracia yo también hice lo mismo unos minutos antes.

Comment: lo siento @OscarGarcia no vi los comentarios de las respuestas

Comment: No pasa nada, a mí también me suele ocurrir. También he aprovechado la edición para corregir el punto y coma final que te faltaba en el código. Por último, te recomiendo echar un vistazo a las recomendaciones PSR, sobre todo a las que hablan de la guía de estilo de codificación (por ejemplo, PSR-2).